# How to programatically find out how many "tabs" a string can fit in?

Tags: java, alignment

Suppose I have a Java String.

```
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789...."
```

Is there a way to find out how many tabs this can "fit" in? So, for instance,

If I print

```
"\t\t\t\t\t..."
```

at what point will the **visual** length of the tabs exceed the string? Or in other words, how to find out the length of the tab space?

Comment: I assume you are using the (somewhat) standard `1 tab == 4 spaces`?

Comment: String.length divide by length of tab space?

Comment: @JesseWebb is there a way to find out the length of the tab space?

Comment: Tab space is entirely dependent on whichever application is displaying the text, and how the user has configured that application.

Comment: @CodeBlue, like Graham mentioned, tabs aren't always the same in all applications. If you are using a monospaced font in a command-prompt like UI, then most people use `1 tab == 4 spaces`. If not, well then you are probably SOL.

Comment: @GrahamBorland is right, although I'll add that it also is dependent on the font size/type as well.  For instance tabbing in a fixed-font is different than an non-proportional font (ie: Courrier vs Arial)

Comment: @GrahamBorland Thanks. So it means there is nothing I can do about it. It depends on the user's configuration.

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming you are using the standard 1 tab = 4 spaces.**

```
String myString = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789....";

//I'm not sure what you want to do with the extra characters, 
//Just replace round by floor, or ceil if you'd like...
//If you want to floor, then just do: int nbOfVisualTabs = myString.length()/4
int nbOfVisualTabs = Math.round( (double)myString.length()/4.0 );
```

Comment: Why are you `floor()`ing integer division?

Comment: So it's easier for the guy to switch to `round()` and `ceil()` (depending on what he wants to do with the extra characters). See the comment next to it. ;-) Of course, Java will truncate it anyway (which is the same result as `floor()ing`).

Comment: @mbinette `myString.length() / 4` already is rounded: it is an integer.

Comment: `round` and `ceil` don't work on integer division. `Math.ceil(5/3)` is still `1` because `5/3` is `1`.

Comment: verdesmarald: you are correct, my bad. Corrected. I just woke up ;-) Edit: Sorry i misinterpreted your first comment!

Answer (score 0):

Well `String.length()` will give you the number of characters in the string, which you would need to divide by the tab-width, which is *usually* 4 or 8. Since tab-width is generally user configurable though, this is not a great approach.

One option if you are going to be displaying in fixed-width font is to print an appropriate number of space characters instead. If the display could be in a proportional font, you will need to come up with something more sophisticated to align elements.

Answer (score 0):

The number of "characters" in a tab varies, so you won't be able to do it statically. The only way I can think of to do this would be to actually physically add them and then test the string to see if it's longer. Something like:

```
while(whateverEventuallyContainsYourString.VisualWidth < yourOtherStringsContainer.VisualWidth) 
{   //Obviously that property doesn't really exist, you'd have to figure something out there.
    myString += "\t";
}
```

But without knowing what context you're working in, I don't even know if that's possible without setting up some more scaffolding.